# Concatenate binary data in matlab?

Tags: matlab, binary, octave

I would like to create a **10 bit** binary value by concatenating *two 4-bit* value and *one 2-bit* value.
eg: *{2'b11,4'b1010,4'b1100}*.

How would I achieve this?

- **strcat(bin2b,bin4b,bin4b)** results with concatenation, but this resultant would be treated as **STRING** by Mlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite a few options there depending on how you want your final result:

```
bin2b  = '11' ;
bin4b1 = '1010' ;
bin4b2 = '1100' ;

b10str = strcat(bin2b,bin4b1,bin4b2)    %// 10 bit value as a string type
b10str = [bin2b bin4b1 bin4b2]          %// 10 bit value as a string type (same than above, shorthand notation for concatenation)

b10dec = bin2dec(b10str)                %// 10 bit value as a numeric type (decimal base)

b10hex = dec2hex(bin2dec(b10str))       %// string type again (hexadecimal base)

b10bitarray = de2bi(b10dec)             %// array of 10 boolean (each represent one bit)
```

That will give you:

```
b10str =
1110101100
b10dec =
   940
b10hex =
3AC
b10bitarray =
     0     0     1     1     0     1     0     1     1     1
```

---

Note: On most PC, binary ordering is "lower endian". Depending on the endianness, you may want to "flip" your bit array before converting it, which can be done with `fliplr`:

```
>> fliplr(b10str)
ans =
0011010111
```

and then convert as above

Comment: For reordering the bits, we can use
de2bi(b10dec,'left-msb')

Comment: @Manojkumar. That is totally correct. However it only works with this specific function/format. It is fine if that's what you use. The 'fliplr' option is more generic, as it can work with any type of array (boolean, numeric, character etc ...).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the best work around is to write a function that does this in C/C++/whatever and use the MEX API to call it from Matlab.

Matlab doesn't let you process types that are not really supported in that way or if you really want to do it in Matlab it will be very ugly and slow.